# Why is $H = J \sum_i (S^x_i S^x_{i+1} + S^y_iS^y_{i+1})$ always gapless for any spin $S$?

Tags: quantum-spin, mathematical-physics, spin-models, phase-diagram, spin-chains

In the following I have in mind antiferromagnetic spin chains in periodic boundary conditions on a chain of even length $L$.

Consider the spin-$S$ spin chain
$$H = J \sum_{i=1}^L (S^x_i S^x_{i+1} + S^y_iS^y_{i+1})$$

It appears to gapless for all $S$, meaning that the energy gap between the ground state and the first excited state vanishes as $L\to \infty$.

I'm most interested in the Hamiltonian for $J>0$, when it is antiferromagnetic. (On the other hand, note that the Hamiltonians with $J$ and $-J$ are related by a simple unitary similarity transformation of $\pi$ rotations about the $z$-axis on every other site, so the Hamiltonians with $\pm J$ have the same eigenvalues. That is, the ferromagnetic and antiferromagnetic versions of the model have the same spectra. Potentially the ferromagnet might give a more natural proof.)

How can I show that $H$ is always gapless for every spin $S$?

---

By the Lieb-Schultz-Mattis theorem, for half-integer spins $\frac{1}{2}, \frac{3}{2},... $, the first excited state is within energy $O(1/L)$ of the ground state and hence $H$ is gapless. However, the usual version of the argument I know doesn't hold for integer spin $S$. The argument I know constructs a variational state with low energy that is orthogonal to the ground state, but the orthogonality is only guaranteed for half-integer spins.

That is, gaplessness is relatively straightforward to prove for half-integer spins $\frac{1}{2}, \frac{3}{2},... $, but it's not clear how to extend the proof to integer spins $S$. Importantly, the addition of a $\Delta \sum_i S^z_i S^z_{i+1}$ term with $\Delta >0$ can open a gap in integer spin chains, so it might be that a very different style of proof from Lieb-Schultz-Mattis will be needed.

Comment: “…and hence H is gapless.” A basic question about language: by gapless do you also include the possibility of a gapped degenerate ground state? If my understanding is correct, the LSM construction cannot distinguish the two possibilities - having nontrivial ground state degeneracy vs being gapless.

Comment: @NandagopalManoj That's a very good point. For example, when we consider a spin-1/2 $XXZ$ chain, LSM applies everywhere despite being gapless for $|\Delta| \leq 1$ and $\mathbb{Z}_2$-symmetry breaking and gapped elsewhere. The splitting between the two dressed cat states in the symmetry broken phase is exponentially small in system size with an O(1) gap above. Typically I would say the $|\Delta|>1$ regime in the spin-1/2 $XXZ$ chain is not gapless.

Comment: @NandagopalManoj However, I think I'm willing to assume that if a result tells us we are either gapless or have nontrivial ground state degeneracy, then we are gapless in the case of $H = J \sum_{i=1}^L (S^x_i S^x_{i+1} + S^y_iS^y_{i+1})$. That is, for this Hamiltonian, I will accept the weaker result that there is at least one eigenstate with energy within $1/L^\alpha$ of the ground state. At the very least, because of the periodic boundary conditions, this will rule out the Haldane phase.

Comment: Do you know for a fact that the spin-S Hamiltonian of the form you wrote is gapless for all S? Is this from your own numerics or is there a reference?

Comment: @NandagopalManoj I have small system-size numerics that the gap is well-described by $O(1)/L$. I also know that for large $S$, the $XXZ$ model ought to go towards the classical $XXZ$ model, which doesn't have any phases with a unique gapped ground state. At large $S$, then, I expect such gapped phases like the Haldane phase will have an extremely tight extent about the Heisenberg point $\Delta=1$; that is, I expect the gapless "$XY$" phase will have a larger and larger extent as $S$ grows given the shrinking Haldane phase.

Comment: @NandagopalManoj In a sense I expect $S=1$ is sort of the hardest case; the gap there opens for any small positive $\Delta$, while for higher integer spin $S$, I expect that one needs a finite $\Delta > \Delta_c >0$ to enter a gapped phase. I'll see if I can find a reference for this.

Comment: @NandagopalManoj A good one is https://arxiv.org/abs/1212.6255. In the integer-$S$ chains in periodic boundary conditions, the gapped phase with a unique ground state (the trivial "even Haldane" and the SPT "odd Haldane" phases) rapidly occupy an extremely tiny portion of the phase diagram. I was surprised by how tiny that portion is (see table II) already for spin-2 and 3.